# Postgres 9.4 -- How do I ignore duplicate key when inserting rows into a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a `story_id` table like this.

```
    Column    |  Type   |                             Modifiers
--------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
 id           | integer | not null default nextval('story_sites_id_seq'::regclass)
 story_id     | integer | not null
 site_id      | integer | not null
```

I want to add new rows with `site_id = 12` and `story_id` which already has `site_id = 70` , here is my query, it works well:

```
INSERT INTO story_sites (story_id, site_id)
SELECT story_id, 12
FROM story_sites
WHERE site_id = 70;
```

But if there're rows which already has `site_id = 12`, I'll get a duplicate key error.

So I want to exclude those duplicate rows, here is my new query, however it doesn't work properly, it inserts nothing when I think it should. Also it seems I can't use `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` in Postgres 9.4. How should I do it ?

```
INSERT INTO story_sites (story_id, site_id)
SELECT story_id, 12
FROM story_sites
WHERE site_id = 70
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT id
    FROM story_sites
    WHERE site_id = 12
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.  You just need a to take the `story_id` into account:

```
INSERT INTO story_sites (story_id, site_id)
    SELECT ss.story_id, 12
    FROM story_sites ss
    WHERE ss.site_id = 70 AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT id
                      FROM story_sites ss2
                      WHERE ss2.site_id = 12 AND ss2.sotry_id = ss.story_id
                     );
```

All that said, this query still has the potential for having problems if multiple inserts are happening at the same time.  What you really should be using is `on conflict do nothing`, which is explained in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-insert.html) for `insert`.

Answer (score -1):

Move up from version 9.4 to 9.5 Do not make **subrequests**. It can lead to decreases in **performance**. **Since Postgres 9.5** you can simply use:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Me') 
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: This will not work in 9.4, which the question is specifically about.